# Mongodb find occurrences

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a **huge** collection of log events on the monogdb, each event has a unique id.

A very simple example:

- user login
- ...
- user created a product
- user created a product
- user renamed a product
- user created a product
- ...
- user logged out

I want to find a specific occurrence (say the 3rd `product create` event) and I want to fetch **10 events before** and **10 events after** this occurrence.
Is that even possible with mongodb?

I'm using Mongoose with NodeJs

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you have unique `timestamp` for the events:

```
Model.find({"event": "user created a product"}).skip(2).exec(function (err, docs)
{
    var myEvent = docs[0];

    Model.find({timestamp: {$gt: myEvent.timestamp}}).limit(10).exec(function (error, records)
    {
        console.log(records);
    });
});
```

**Update:**
If you don't have timestamp for each event (which would be really wrong), this should work:

```
Model.find({"event": "user created a product"}).skip(2).exec(function (err, docs)
{
    var myEvent = docs[0];

    Model.find({"_id": { "$lt" : myEvent._id}}).count().exec(function(error,count)
    {
        Model.find().skip(count).limit(10).exec(function(e,records)
        {
            console.log(records);
        })
    })
});
```